# What's the significance of all the masks in the Osborn mansion?

Tags: marvel, spider-man, spider-man-2002

Does it continue the running theme throughout the film? The things I can think of are:

> Don't ever be ashamed of who you are -Norman

and

> Then why does he wear a mask? What's he got to hide? -Jameson

Obviously, the two main characters wear a mask (Green Goblin and Spider-Man). Is the totem/mask scene trying to show the split personality of Norman Osborn/Green Goblin?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a case of the tail wagging the dog. Raimi decided that Osborne needed to be masked in order to become a (non-goofy) recognisable Green Goblin character. To that end, the producers need to show the evolution of his mask and hence decided to add masks to the mansion.

> “Once we got on the set, the costume 
>   wasn’t too big of a deal,” he [Defoe] adds. “The suit 
>   was designed and very functional, and I had 
>   to wear the mask. It was a hard mask, and 
>   some people even referred to it as a helmet. I 
>   could put the mask on and take it off, and 
>   **there’s a good tie-in to the mask in the film. 
>   You see Norman Osborn in his study, and it’s 
>   clear that he collects masks. You also see the 
>   suit and the mask being developed in his laboratory. So they don’t come out of nowhere. 
>   In the same way that Peter designs his Spider-Man costume, Norman inadvertently 
>   designs his Green Goblin costume.”**
>
> <sub><sup>[Starlog #299 - Shadow of the Green Goblin](https://archive.org/details/starlog_magazine-299JPG)</sup></sub>